# Converting excel file to SQL server database ERROR: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 2

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to convert an excel sheet to a sql server database using apache poi on java, but I'm running into a bug in doing this.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 2.
```

I am able to see the database on the sql server, but it is empty.

I added debug statements to see where it was getting to and it gets through quite a bit of the excel sheet before throwing this error.

Assume that the data is only strings or ints

Any help would be appreciated

here is my code

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Purge_Temp ([Issue ID], [Service Order ID], [Service Order Status], [Service Order Priority], "
                    + " [WH Order Number], [Region Network], [Asset Type], [Product Line], [Product ID], [Product Name], "
                    + " [Product Part Number], [Server Generation], [Server Type], [Asset Serial Number], [Source Location Name], "
                    + " [POP Name], [Destination Territory], [Destination Country], [Pop Id], [Logistics Coordinator], "
                    + " [Day of Item Booked Date], [Day of Item Shipped Date], [Measure Names], [Service Order Age]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, "
                    + " ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement inputStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql); 
            
            rowIterator.next(); // skip the header row
            
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row nextRow = rowIterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
                int count = 0;
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    count++;
                    
                    Cell nextCell = cellIterator.next();
                    int columnIndex = nextCell.getColumnIndex();
                    
                    if (nextCell.getCellType() == CellType.BLANK || nextCell.toString().isEmpty()) {
                       inputStatement.setNull(columnIndex + 1, java.sql.Types.NULL);
                    }
                    else {
                        try {
                            if (nextCell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) {
                                String toInsert = nextCell.getStringCellValue();
                                inputStatement.setString(columnIndex + 1, toInsert);
                                 System.out.println("Cell Value: " + nextCell.toString());
                                    System.out.println("Column Index: " + columnIndex);
                            }
                            else if (nextCell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                                double numericValue = nextCell.getNumericCellValue();
                                int intValue = (int) numericValue;
                                inputStatement.setInt(columnIndex + 1, intValue);
                            }
                        }
                        catch(SQLException e) {
                            int val = (int) nextCell.getNumericCellValue();
                            String toInsert = Integer.toString(val);
                            inputStatement.setString(columnIndex + 1, toInsert);
                            System.out.println(e);
                        }

                    }
                    inputStatement.addBatch();
                 
                    if (count % batchSize == 0) {
                        inputStatement.executeBatch();
                    } 
                    
 
                }
          
                
            }
            workbook.close();
             
            // execute the remaining queries
            inputStatement.executeBatch();
```

Comment: cellIterator only returns cells that have values so it can skip empty cells. Try using a for loop to loop from 0 to row.getLastCellNum(). Inside the loop, call row.getCell(index, MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL). If this returns null, you have an empty cell.